# Excel macro that updates data coming from a database (IBM TM1) to run with VBScript causes problems

Tags: excel, vba, database, vbscript, cognos-tm1

I have written an Excel macro that automatically refreshes the data using the function, (CognosOfficeAutomationObject.RefreshAllData) that comes from TM1.
If I run the macro from Excel it works as well. But if I execute the macro with a VBScript an error occurs. Can it be that VBScript always opens excel in protected mode?
Do you have any experience with updating data from a database and VBScript?

VBScript

```
Set BuReport = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
BuReport.Application.Run "'...... .xlsm'!LogonAndRefresh_Click_Test"
BuReport.DisplayAlerts = False
BuReport.Application.Quit
Set BuReport = Nothing
```

Thank you!

[image: Before Macro starts]

[image: Before Macro starts]

[image: After Macro starts]

[image: After Macro starts]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I get a #value error.
But I don't get this error when I start the macro directly in Excel.

Comment: I have added 4 photos for better explanation. Sorry it is a #NV error.

The first two screenshots are before running the macro and the last two are after running it.

Comment: Pretty difficult to offer suggestions without seeing what's in `DBRA`